# How do I display how many are Online

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I would like to know how I would get something like this..

```
There are 7 Members Online
```

Using my Timestamp which is set as format

```
2016-04-25 19:27:00
```

I would like this to be within a 30 min gap. This is how I tried it, But it did not work.

```
 <?php $logged = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(time) FROM users where time >= 600 ;") or die(mysql_error()); ?> 

There are <?php echo $logged; ?> Members Online
```

Comment: This query is selecting the number of date entries where time is greater than 600.  Does "time" hold a timestamp or a difference in time?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You can't just do `<?php echo $logged; ?>` if that's all you're using.

Comment: I built a system similar to this just a few week ago actually. Know this for a fact.

Comment: Mean`while`, back at the Ranch.

Comment: well this one's gone staler than a piece of bread left out on the counter for two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as theCount
FROM users 
where login_time + interval 30 minute >= now()
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: It just showed "There are 1 Member Online" but no-one was logged in and the database last time was 1 hour ago

Comment: @JoeBills you aren't showing any data in your setup for juergen. As far as we know, you have datetime issues off by a few hours based on timezone particles PHP vs Mysql

Comment: @JoeBills *"It just showed "There are 1 Member Online""* - which is normal, seeing what you're using here. You didn't even fetch/loop over results, far as I can tell by what you posted. The `1` you're seeing means your query didn't fail.

Comment: Right @Fred-ii- he is not going into the result set. Go into the resultset and get the 1 row for `theCount`

Comment: @Drew *Esattamente!* - I built me one of those fancy "who's online" script just a few weeks ago in PDO actually, but I'm not about just to give it away, should I? Should I? *lol* - Nah, on second thought... that would probably just open up a great big can of *"you know what"*. Funny what 3 lines of code can do too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not sure you are qualified :p

Comment: @Drew You're right, I'm not (not in PDO). Mine was MySQLi_, different animal but from the same zoo. *My bad*.

Comment: I was just joking Fred. You are qualified in my book

Comment: I actually managed to edit the code, and and i put `SELECT COUNT(*) as total_online FROM users WHERE login_time + interval 30 minute >= now()` and that seemed to work. Thank you all for your help!